# determine if ffmpeg libfreetype is installed

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg

is there any way i can determine if libfreetype is installed on a remote server ?

i don't have root access so i can only run commands via exec(). when i run a simple `ffmpeg` command all i get is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
    [1] => usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
    [2] => 
)
```

my best guess is that it should be listed on `ffmpeg -version` but i'm not sure

Comment: libfreetype may be installed on the remote server, but it does not mean that the remote ffmpeg has been compiled with `--enable-libfreetype`.

Comment: but is there any way i can check if it was compiled with `--enable-libfreetype`

Comment: You should show your relevant PHP code and not only just the output.